# Library for doc/xls to pdf/tiff conversion

Tags: .net, pdf-generation

I am looking for a library that will allow the following conversions:
MS Word -> PDF or TIFF
MS Excel -> PDF or TIFF
PDF -> TIFF
TIFF -> PDF

I am using .net 3.5.  I'll be using asp most likely, but this could end up being a winform app.

The library does not have to be free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx

Best I've used; supports all the transformations you mention if you get their Apose.Words and Apose.Cells products.